# How to change BackColor to "none"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backcolor

how could I change `BackColor` property to "none"?
I just want to place come Labels on my gif animation, but couldn`t change this white color on label backgroung.

[image]

Comment: try `Color.Transparent`

Comment: Have you tried Transparent?

Comment: Setting `BackColor` of labels  to `Color.Transparent` is not enough. You should also add labels as children of `PictureBox`.

Comment: Don't use Labels and just draw that text.

Comment: pictureBox1.SendToBack();
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
 label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
This helped;